# Meaning of the word "register" in the following context

Tags: meaning

Dating to about 3000 BCE, the Warka Vase was a narrow, three-foot high alabaster cylinder decorated with three bands of carved figures— each band represents a different level of the world. The bottom is water—the wavy lines perhaps depicting the banks of the Euphrates on which Uruk was situated. Above the water is a band depicting domes- ticated plants, apparently the irrigated fields that once surrounded the ancient city. Above this is a parade of alternating rams and ewes. The world of mankind occupies the central **register** on the vase. Naked men walk in file—husbandmen—each carrying a basket or an amphora, evi- dently the commodities collected and processed from the domesticated world below. Their lack of individuality suggests that they themselves are commodities—perhaps symbolizing human labor as opposed to humanity. Finally, at the top of the vase strong textis the world of the temple—a magnificent procession of animals and people with a priest at their head who is presenting gifts to a temple priestess or to the goddess Inanna. In this **register** is an image of narrow vessels just like the vase itself.

Comment: The ***registers*** here are the *three **bands***, representing different ***levels*** - metaphorically extended from the definition [*A particular **part of the range** of a voice or instrument.*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/register)

Comment: ...more specifically from the full (subscription-only) [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/161292?rskey=ktMnaO&result=1#eid), **register** (n) definition 15: *(Art and Architecture) Each of a number of bands or sections into which a design, facade, etc., is divided.*

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you so much!